# Keeping model while navigation using angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I just started to learn angularjs and I have a question:

I am trying to create a view with a table of entities with an update button. When the Upadte button is pressed I want to navigate to another view to edit the entity.

In my main page I used this to load my different view into:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I used ASP.NET MVC to create partial views for the list of entites and the update form.

These two partial views use the same angular controller.

To display the list:

```
<div ng-controller="CompaniesController">
    <table id="tblCompaniesCollection">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
 ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="Company in Companies">
            <tr>
                <td><span>{{Company.Name}}</span></td>
 ...
                <td>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="ChangeView(Company)">Go to edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

To update:

```
<div ng-controller="CompaniesController">
    <table id="tblCompanyToEdit">
        <tbody >
            <tr >
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><span>{{CompanyToEdit.Name}}</span></td>
                </tr>
    ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the ChangeView(Company) function I do the following:

```
$scope.ChangeView = function (Company) {

    $scope.CompanyToEdit = Company
    $location.path('/EditCompany');
};
```

What I tried to achieve:

- Have a simple partial view for the view of list of entites and the
  update view.
- After the view of list of entites is loaded into it's place, it
  gets the data from the same web application via WEB API
  controller.

It is working till this point.

What is not working:

- When I click the button store the selected entity in the
  `$scope.CompanyToEdit` and load it into the view.
- This way I would not have to create another request to the server to 
  get the company to edit, but the angular controller recreated on
  navigating and I lost my data.

How do you solve this wiht angular? Please tell me if my aproach is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with the same controller.

The reason is that when changing views, and I assume you're changing states, the controller is loaded again and is going through an initialization process.

Meaning that `$scope.CompanyToEdit` won't have a value and will be undefined, unless you initialize that in the controller.

**What you need to do**, is use a service to keep the data and use the controller to access that service. The service will keep the value since while you're navigating in the same SPA, services exist as singletons.

Inject the service to the controller and access the data there.